# Want my h2 DAO tests in to use tables from schema provided and not auto-generate Tables. (Spring Boot Java)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

In my spring boot application, I have written unit tests for my DAO layer using an in memory db h2. Uptill now, I was relying on the auto generate feature of hibernate. This is what my application.properties looked like:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

I now want the tables to be created according to a set of create SQL statements. I have now edited my properties to this:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:new;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-11;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=runscript from 'classpath:/init-db.sql'
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Now, when I run my tests, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
     at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(    DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate     SessionFactory
    ...
    ... 25 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build     Hibernate SessionFactory
    ...
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    ...
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "TESTINFO" already exists; SQL statement:
create table TESTINFO
(
id number not null,
edit_sequence number not null,
flavor varchar(50),
source varchar(40),
creation_date timestamp,
last_modified timestamp,
) [42101-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateTable.update(CreateTable.java:117)
    at org.h2.command.dml.RunScriptCommand.execute(RunScriptCommand.java:78)
    at org.h2.command.dml.RunScriptCommand.update(RunScriptCommand.java:57)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:260)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:224)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:154)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:354)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:116)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:100)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(    DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectio    nAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.ExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(    ExtractionContextImpl.java:62)
    ... 53 more
```

I am guessing that when I run the test, spring boot is automatically generating the tables? But when i remove the part `INIT=runscript from 'classpath:/init-db.sql'` but still keep this line: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`, I get an exception that it is not able to find the table `TESTINFO`.

How do I make the unit tests use the table schema that I define?

UPDATE: I have also tried `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`. Still not the same table already exists error.

Comment: JPA comes with its own schema generation properties, yet you use implementation-specific ones and lose portability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

and put your schema in `classpath:/schema.sql` file

For details read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html